# Dart : how to identify an object?

Tags: flutter, dart

in my app I've got this small sub-widget in a list that redirects me to the profile page of the author of the ad with a `Hero` animation. The problem that I'm facing right now, is that if there's two ads with the same author, there will be two hero tags which are the same (which is normal 'cause they redirect to the same page). But flutter doesn't allow to have multiple Hero widgets with the same hero tag.

[image]

A solution would be to get a value that is proper to the object and that would be different even if the objects have the same properties. A kind of equivalent to the reference, or the memory location in java. But I haven't found such a thing for dart on the internet :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think the best way is just to generate a random tag, and pass it to the destiantion page :

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final String randomTag = Uuid().v4();
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        context.read<NavigatorBloc>().add(GoToProfileDetailScreen(author: author, tag : randomTag));
      },
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          SizedBox(
            width: isDetail ? 30.0 : 20.0,
            height: isDetail ? 30.0 : 20.0,
            child: Hero(
              tag: randomTag,
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot see directly of adress of your instance in dart, but
You can use `id` in model if you have for tag or Instance of Class f.e Entity().

Comment: Which image are you talking about ? The profile picture ? That wouldn't work as there will still be multiple hero widgets with the same tag.

Comment: Sorry i was confused with my last answer on stackoverflow Now I edited my answer

Comment: If you send me your code  i ll help to implement

Comment: @user54517 What do u mean with the same tag? If you have id field in your entity you can use for tag and id should unique. If you mean about an instance, it should also be unique because it is located at a different address.

Comment: I was using the author id as a tag, but I realized that if an author publishes two adds (like in the picture), that couldn't work as there will be the same tag multiple times

Comment: does you have id for publish?

Comment: Or simple you can do like this

```Hero(
              tag:
YourDataClass(),),```

Comment: In YourDataClass class you can override hashFunction and == opertor or use equatable package from pub.dev